# Special "Special" Character Support HTML (in email)

Tags: php, html, css, email, phpmailer

I'm trying to send an email with PHP mailer, I'm reading an HTML and passing it as the body.

```
file_get_contents('email.html');
```

but when I'm receiving the mail some of the characters like `©` `“` `”` are getting converted like `Â©` `â€œ` `â€`.

I have `<meta charset="UTF-8"/>` under the `body` tag as well as I tried that under `head` tag. When I open the `email.html` in Safari (as a web page) or I open the email from Gmail in Safari `<meta charset="UTF-8"/>` seems to work, but inside Mac Mail it's not working.

[image: screenshot]

I have a CSS file linked in the HTML so if it's possible to fix that from CSS that would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the character set that PHPMailer uses like this:

```
$mail->CharSet = ‘utf-8’;
```